# Check matching file names in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I set the following code to;

1. Only find the matching file name without extension. Eg: if the file name in Google drive path is "test1.pdf" I want to find matches for files with "test1" and populate the hyperlink (in column T) with full file name (in Column U).
2. What additional code should I use in the below code to if I setup a time-trigger?
3. If the file is in a sub-folder inside the parent folder, how to find such files if I only provide the parent folder ID? And possible indicate the sub-folder name in Column V

Thank you in advance everyone. Apologies if the question is unclear.

````
  
  var folderId = '#FolderId';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
  var extension = '.xlsx';
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  var RowSize=sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues().filter(String).length; //calculate max value of rows
  
  var file_name=sheet.getRange('B2:B'+RowSize).getValues()
  var file_checker=sheet.getRange('Q2:Q'+RowSize).getValues()
  
  for (i = 0; i < file_name.length; i++) {
  
    if (file_checker[i][0]=="Complete"){break;}  
    
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(file_name[i][0]+extension)
  
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next(); 
      var file_url =  childFile.getUrl() 
      sheet.getRange(i+2,18).setValue(file_url);
  } // while

} //for
  
} // function```
````

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: This current code only picks if it has the mentioned file extension. Since the folder will have multiple file types, I'm trying to figure out a way to match the file name without extension. Looking to run the code automatically, I dont know how to set it up since it will not be active sheet. Users who are uploading to the folder might create additional folders and upload the file I requested, so trying to scan through them as well. Hope the clarification is fine.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. I could understand about `This current code only picks if it has the mentioned file extension. Since the folder will have multiple file types, I'm trying to figure out a way to match the file name without extension.`. 2. I cannot understand about `Looking to run the code automatically, I dont know how to set it up since it will not be active sheet.`. In your script, when your script is the container-bound script, `source.getSheetByName('Sheet1')` can be used as "Sheet1". How about this?

Comment: 3. I cannot understand about `Users who are uploading to the folder might create additional folders and upload the file I requested, so trying to scan through them as well.`.

Comment: 2. I'm trying to do a time-trigger for this so it runs automatically. But what additional code should I use to run this as a time-trigger (during a time trigger, there is no active sheet right?)?

Comment: ```In your script, when your script is the container-bound script, source.getSheetByName('Sheet1') can be used as "Sheet1". How about this?```. I'm new to scripting so unable to comment on this. What I'm trying to do is find a file in Google Drive that matches the name in Google Sheet.

Comment: ```I cannot understand about Users who are uploading to the folder might create additional folders and upload the file I requested, so trying to scan through them as well.```. multiple users will upload files to Google Drive, so they might upload the file in a sub-folder instead of the parent folder. Eg: Folder A is the parent folder, and Folder A.1 is the sub-folder inside it. So the user might drop the file in folder A.1. Apologies for being too clear, I edited the question again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About `In your script, when your script is the container-bound script, source.getSheetByName('Sheet1') can be used as "Sheet1". How about this?`, when your script is run by the time-driven trigger, did you confirm whether `sheet` is `null`? If `sheet` is `null`, please check the sheet name. I couldn't understand about `Eg: Folder A is the parent folder, and Folder A.1 is the sub-folder inside it. So the user might drop the file in folder A.1.`.

Comment: That is totally fine. I did not setup the time-trigger yet, I asked because another script I have in the file required a separate code to be put to run the time trigger. With regard to the folder, I have the main folder in drive named "Completed", inside that folder other users may create a subfolder named "Services" and upload the file to this subfolder. Im trying to find the file, irrespective whether it is in "Completed" folder or "Services" folder inside it. Hope this clarifies. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about `another script I have in the file required a separate code to be put to run the time trigger.`. And, in your case, there are many folders of the same folder name of `Services` in the folder of `Completed`?